# dbGetQuery with multiple parameters

Tags: r, postgresql, dbi

I have a problem. I would like to pass **"querys1"** as parameters in **dbGetQuery** but I can't get the data I'm interested in.  However, I can get my data when I run **dbGetQuery** with **"querys2"** and **"Filter2"**.

```
Filter1 <- "State" #input$state
Filter2 <- "Luxury" #input$home

query1 <-
  paste0(paste0("$", seq_along(Filter1)), collapse = ", ")

query2 <-
  paste0(paste0("$", seq_along(Filter2)), collapse = ", ")

querys1 <- paste0("SELECT *
               FROM table
               WHERE state IN (",
                 query1,
                 ") AND home IN (", 
                 query2,
                 ")")

querys2 <- paste0("SELECT *
                FROM table
                WHERE home IN (",
                  query2,
                  ")")

data1 <- dbGetQuery(conn, querys2, as.list(Filter2))
```

How can I pass both Where clauses ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: What happens when you run `querys1`? Is there are error, or a warning? Do you get data back, but not the data that you want? What does "can't get the data I'm interested in" mean?

Comment: Seems like you might be missing some single quotes in the SQL syntax, but if that's the problem I don't see how `querys2` would work either...

Comment: Hello @GregorThomas, thanks for your reply. I was able to get Luxiry data with querys2 as expected. With querys1 i got an error due to parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are sequencing along *each* of your filters instead of *all* of your filters. We can see why this is a problem with:

```r
querys1
# [1] "SELECT *\n               FROM table\n               WHERE state IN ($1) AND home IN ($1)"
```

(That is, both sets are `$1`.) What this means is that `state` and `home` are compared against the same literal value, not the first of each vector. The `$`-numbers need to be sequencing along all parameters combined.

With length-1 for each of your `Filter`s, it seems trivial, but I'm inferring they can be "1 or more", so we need to do a little more work.

```r
query1 <-
  paste0(paste0("$", seq_along(Filter1)), collapse = ", ")

query2 <-
  paste0(paste0("$", length(Filter1) + seq_along(Filter2)), collapse = ", ")

querys1 <- paste0("SELECT *
               FROM table
               WHERE state IN (",
                 query1,
                 ") AND home IN (", 
                 query2,
                 ")")

querys2 <- paste0("SELECT *
                FROM table
                WHERE home IN (",
                  query2,
                  ")")
```

Now we see

```r
querys1
# [1] "SELECT *\n               FROM table\n               WHERE state IN ($1) AND home IN ($2)"
querys2
# [1] "SELECT *\n                FROM table\n                WHERE home IN ($2)"
```

Recognize that once you embed `$` in a query, you are beholden to having parameters of a list that long. So even though we may not be using the `$1` parameter, we still need `params=` to include it.

The queries would then be:

```r
data1 <- dbGetQuery(conn, querys1, as.list(c(Filter1, Filter2)))
data2 <- dbGetQuery(conn, querys2, as.list(c(Filter1, Filter2)))
```

If you prefer to not include `Filter1` in your `querys2` retrieval, then you need to reform the `$`-counting without `Filter1` consideration.

---

One alternative to this where you can be a little looser in controlling the parameters and `$`-referencing is to use a helper function that converts a non-counting placeholder (such as `?`, used by many other DBMSes for parameter binding), then pass the query and list of params, and it'll replace the `?` literals with the `$`-counts.

I'll expand this a little to handle "IN" 1-or-more vectors.

```r
#' @param query length-1 character, with "?name" named binding locations
#' @param params named list of params, names correspond to "?name" binds
xlate <- function(query, params) {
  stopifnot(length(query) == 1L)
  gre <- gregexpr("\\?[A-Za-z]+", query)
  nms <- sub("^\\?", "", regmatches(query, gre)[[1]])

  newparams <- params[nms]
  
  leng <- lengths(newparams)
  leng <- c(0, leng[-length(leng)])
  qmarks <- mapply(function(pre, vec) {
    paste(paste0("$", pre + seq_along(vec)), collapse = ",")
  }, leng, newparams)
  newparams <- unname(unlist(newparams))

  regmatches(query, gre) <- list(qmarks)

  list(query = query, params = newparams)
}
```

And its use should be intuitive:

```r
xlate("select * from table where state in (?st) or home in (?hm)", list(st="QQ", hm=c("abc","quux")))
# $query
# [1] "select * from table where state in ($1) or home in ($2,$3)"
# $params
# [1] "QQ"   "abc"  "quux"
xlate("select * from table where home in (?hm)", list(st="QQ", hm=c("abc","quux")))
# $query
# [1] "select * from table where home in ($1,$2)"
# $params
# [1] "abc"  "quux"
xlate("select * from table where state in (?hm) or home in (?hm)", list(st="QQ", hm=c("abc","quux")))
# $query
# [1] "select * from table where state in ($1,$2) or home in ($3,$4)"
# $params
# [1] "abc"  "quux" "abc"  "quux"
```

This would be used as:

```r
tmp <- xlate("select * from table where state in (?hm) or home in (?hm)", list(st="QQ", hm=c("abc","quux")))
res <- dbGetQuery(con, tmp$query, params = tmp$params)
```

Comment: Hello @r2evans, thank you a lot for your reply, It solved my problem perfectly and I understand better now.